# Bash shell: How to parse file names

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

So I have several files in this format:

```
fileYYYY-MM-DD-HH.foo
nameOfFileYYYY-MM-DD-HH.bar
FileNameYYYY-MM-DD-HH
NameYYYY-MM-DD-HH
```

Where the only thing in common is the

```
YYYY-MM-DD-HH
YYYY - Year
MM   - Month (2 digit)
DD   - Day   (2 digit)
HH   - Hour  (2 digit)
```

before the extension, if the file has one.

My problem is that I have to take that date compare it against a bunch of files with the same name but a different date and then delete all except the 4 most recent files.

---

E.g.:
Have this

```
foo2013-01-01-13
foo2013-11-02-13
foo2014-01-01-13
foo2014-11-05-13
foo2015-04-23-13
foo2015-08-02-12
```

And get this:

```
foo2014-01-01-13
foo2014-11-05-13
foo2015-04-23-13
foo2015-08-02-12
```

---

I really have no clue on how to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your awk has the patsplit function, you're in luck:

```
sort -r |
awk '{patsplit($0,a,"[1-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]",s)}
     s[0]!=p0 || s[1]!=p1 {n=0; p0=s[0]; p1=s[1]}
     s[0]==p0 && s[1]==p1 && n<4 {print}
     {++n}'
```

This should print the files to save. If you want the list of files to delete, change n<4 to n>3.

Comment: It doesn't and this script will be used in various linux systems so I need a more "broad" way to do this :/

Comment: Do the various systems have perl? Or do you have perl and a way to compile it?

Comment: Thanks for accepting it as "the answer". I realized later that patsplit isn't needed, only split. So this code is more complicated (and less generally usable) than it should be. Should I add the "split" solution?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in several steps. For example create two files:

**pr.awk**

```
BEGIN {
    # build regexp
    d = "[0-9]"
    YYYY = d d d d
    MM = d d
    DD = d d
    HH = d d
    sep = "-"
    r = YYYY sep MM sep DD sep HH
}

{
    fn = $0 # file name

    match($0, r)
    tag = substr(fn, RSTART, RLENGTH) # date tag

    sub(r, "", $0) # remove a tag
    rst = $0       # rest of the file name

    # sort in reverse order
    print rst, tag, fn  | "sort -r"
}
```

**del.awk**

```
{
    nkeep = 4 # keep this number of files with the same `rst'
    rst = $1
    fn  = $3

    if (++nf[rst] <= nkeep)
        print fn
}
```

Input file **input.dat**

```
foo2013-01-01-13
foo2013-11-02-13
foo2014-01-01-13
2013-02-02-03bar
2013-08-02-01bar
2012-04-02-01bar
2013-08-08-01bar
2011-08-08-01bar
foo2014-11-05-13
foo2015-04-23-13
foo2015-08-02-12
```

Run a pipe: `awk -f pr.awk input.dat | awk -f del.awk`

```
foo2015-08-02-12
foo2015-04-23-13
foo2014-11-05-13
foo2014-01-01-13
2013-08-08-01bar
2013-08-02-01bar
2013-02-02-03bar
2012-04-02-01bar
```